# Push Notifications for Windows Application

Tags: wpf, notifications

I'm trying to develop a chat application for windows.As in all chat applications I also have a requirement of showing notifications whenever the User gets a message.Now,what I want is how can I show a notification and clicks on that notification will have to perform some task.How can I achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want a notification within your application. like a popup or do you require something outside your application? like a toast notification?

Comment: @Sam I want Toast notification

Comment: use the toastnotificationextensions (https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit)